# Who is the person whom Allah gave his signs, but he detached from them?

Tags: quran, tafseer, surat-al-araf

While reciting [surat al-'Araaf](http://legacy.quran.com/7/175-176) I passed by these verses:

> And recite to them, [O Muhammad], the news of *him to whom we gave [knowledge of] Our signs, but he detached himself from them*; so Satan pursued him, and he became of the deviators. **(175)**
>   And if We had willed, we could have elevated him thereby, but he adhered [instead] to the earth and followed his own desire. So his example is like that of the dog: if you chase him, he pants, or if you leave him, he [still] pants. That is the example of the people who denied Our signs. So relate the stories that perhaps they will give thought. **(176)**

My question is the person whom have been given the signs of Allah and who has detached himself from them a "Known " person our is this verse only a general example, what do tafseer books say about "him"?

Comment: have you looked up any tafseer your self? because if we link to some tafseer site here, most probably our answer will be deleted for not being our own words.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal If i wanted i could answer the question myself, as these are the kinds of answers i love to research about

Comment: That's exactly why i asked you brother. And i still believe you will give better answer than most of the community here :)

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal thanks for your confidence, but I'm a bit busy and sick these days. And I really had  this question in mind and thought it could be nice to ask it here.

Comment: May Allah accept your curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The known reason for these verses is the true story of a man of bani esrael, talks varies about him and alsahaba said about him in sunnah.

These verses have been descended from god to tell the prophet mohammad to tell the story of the man who detached himself from the true signs of god

prophet mohammad said this story to be an example and teach alsahaba

i did not find an english source for that but i know it in arabic and i translated the most important thing in this because there is more than one story but all of them point to this fact

reference:
[Tafsir ibn Kathir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=49&surano=7&ayano=175).

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't it King Saul? He didn't want to be replaced by David; so he pursued and tried to kill him. David had to exile himself in caves for safety. He did have a loyal friend which was one of King Saul's son who kept him updated with the steps of Saul and his army. Saul even attempted to have the prophet Samuel conjured up by a soothsayer (think i spelled it correctly) to question about his suspicions etc...See some of the major ways Saul went astray?